# How could I check the value of an aggregation function inside the same query?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

This MySQL query gives me this error `'Unknown column 'winnings' in 'field list'`

```
SELECT  
o.user_id, 
sum(case when o.result = 1 or o.result=2 or o.result = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as tahmins_no, 
sum(case when o.result = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as winnings, 
sum(case when o.result = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as loses,
sum(case when winnings = 10 then 0.5 else 0 end) as counter 
FROM `odds_tahminler` o
```

I know that `winnings` is the value of the `sum()` aggregation function, But is there any way to check the `winnings` value within the query?

Comment: I see only `o` table, where is your `u` table?

Comment: @Alex you are right I edit it

Comment: what do you mean by `to check the *winnings* value`?

Comment: @Alex to see how much this value contain

Comment: ? query result will show that ? doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an aggregated column inside the select. However you can use a subquery to obtain the counter value after all the aggregated columns have been computed.

How is the counter value calculated? I assumed that the counter should be *(winnings - 10) / 2* if there's at least 10 winnings and 0 otherwise. In that case you can obtain it with this query

```
SELECT O.*,
       GREATEST( (O.winnings - 10) / 2, 0) as counter            
  FROM
       (
          SELECT u.username, 
                 o.user_id, 
                 sum(case when o.result = 1 or o.result=2 or o.result = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as tahmins_no, 
                 sum(case when o.result = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as winnings, 
                 sum(case when o.result = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as loses
            FROM `odds_tahminler` o
       ) as O
```

Comment: I think you miss something in this answer I want the `counter` to add 1 for each continues 10 `winnings`. is it possible ? 
I mean we should make an increment to the counter each 10 continuous winnings and then make the winnings value zero and also if we face a lost before reaching 10 continuous winnings we should also make the winnings zero

Comment: Ok, so you want to count how many 10-winning streaks there are. Sadly you can't do it with an aggregation function.

It must be a way to do it but I need time to think about it, I would answer again if I find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

you can try:

```
SELECT 
o.user_id, 
sum(case when o.result = 1 or o.result=2 or o.result = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as tahmins_no, 
sum(case when o.result = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as winnings, 
sum(case when o.result = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as loses,
sum(case when winnings = 10 then 0.5 else 0 end) as counter 
FROM `odds_tahminler` o
GROUP BY o.user_id
HAVING counter>2
```